# setValue:forUndefinedKey: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key boldColor in iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift

I have this custom label I'm using across my app but when I run my app on devices on ios 12 it crashes with this error
`NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<EFontRegular 0x10999e050> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key boldColor`
but works fine in ios 13 and above. Any help will be appreciated. All the other solutions online didn't work for me

```
@IBDesignable
final class EFontRegular: BaseUILabel {
    override var fontType: UIFont? {
        return UIFont(name: EFontConstant.Name.regular.rawValue, size: fontSize)
    }
}
```

```
@IBDesignable
class BaseUILabel: UILabel {
        
    @IBInspectable var fontSize: CGFloat {
        return self.font.pointSize
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var fontType: UIFont? {
        return UIFont(name: EFontConstant.Name.regular.rawValue, size: EFontConstant.Size.regular.rawValue)
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var stringToColor: String = "" {
        didSet {
            let alignment: NSTextAlignment = alignCenter ? .center : .left
            attributedText = text?.lineSpacedWithInlineColor(lineSpacing, alignment, stringToColor: stringToColor)
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var boldColor: UIColor {
        traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .light ? .black : .white
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var stringToBold: String = "" {
        didSet {
            let alignment: NSTextAlignment = alignCenter ? .center : .left
            attributedText = text?.lineSpacedWithInlineColor(lineSpacing, alignment, stringToColor: stringToBold, color: boldColor, bold: true, boldTextSize: fontSize)
        }
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        commonInit()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ___" errors are often caused when you have a storyboard with a link to a property that doesn't exist in the class it links to. I suggest searching your storyboard files for occurrences of "boldColor".

Comment: Done that, the classes with the bold color don't even have storyboards attached to them. Besides it works for ios 13 and above

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, which I resolved by removing unwanted or extra connections which you are not using in the storyboard. For me, this error generally occurred as I copied all the storyboards from one project and pasted them into the new project, and changed the component names and actions but forgot to remove the old names and actions for the UI Components in the storyboard.
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMQ9u.png)